# What is substitute for strstream's pcount and freeze in stringstream?

Tags: c++, stringstream, strstream

I have old c++ code using strstream and using pcount and freeze methods of the same.
I want to use stringstream class instead. What are the substitute for pcount and freeze methods of strstream? The code is something like this:

```
strstream log; // this will change to: stringstream log;

if (log.pcount()) //????
{
    log << ends;
    *myLog << log.str() << logmsg;
}

log.freeze(0); //????
```

Comment: Advice: use `stringstream` instead.

Comment: @chris, sorry, the text of the question said he wanted to use `sstream`.

Comment: @Shahbaz,@chris: Corrected the text of the question..Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`freeze()` is something which has and need no replacement, its purpose is the handling of memory.

`log.pcount()` can be replaced with `log.str().size()` if your stringstream  is output only. If not, I don't think there is a good replacement. BTW, ends is unneeded as well.

Comment: How about `log.tellp()` ?